# Construction of connected closed oriented $4d-$dimensional manifold whose has only middle homology group is nontrivial.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

How we can construct 4d-dimensional connected closed oriented manifold whose has property
$H^{0}=\mathbb{Q},\quad H^{2d}=\mathbb{Q},\quad H^{4d}=\mathbb{Q}.$
 Few well known examples are $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ for $d=1$, $\mathbb{H}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ for $d=2$ and $\mathbb{O}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ for $d=4.$ 
If anybody has an idea or references for $d>4$ or other examples for $d=1,2,4,$ please share with me. Also, for $d=3.$

Comment: I have some vague recollection that this is actually impossible for $d \ge 4$, at least integrally. Not sure about rationally.

Comment: The Cayley plane is 16 dimensional, so I think you mean that it corresponds to $d=4$.

Comment: sorry, I will correct my question.

Comment: See e.g. Hatcher. Algebraic topology, section 4L (cor. 4L.10 etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem A of [*Smooth manifolds with prescribed rational cohomology ring*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1801) by Fowler and Su shows that the only dimensions in which a smooth such manifold can exist is $n = 2^a$ or $8(2^a + 2^b)$ where $a \neq b$. Note, while the authors are concerned with simply connected such manifolds, the conclusion does not require any hypothesis on the fundamental group.

In the earlier paper [*Rational analogues of projective planes*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3274), Su showed that there are infinitely many homeomorphism types of such manifolds in dimension $32$.

In a recent paper, [*On dimensions supporting a rational projective plane*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07892), Kennard and Su show that there are examples in dimensions $128$ and $256$ (Theorem A). Moreover, there are infinitely many dimensions of the form $2^a$ and infinitely many of the form $8(2^a + 2^b)$ with $a \neq b$ for which there is no such manifold which is simply connected.

Note, all known examples have dimension of the form $2^a$.

Answer (score 2):

Over integer see paper of J. Eells, Jr. & N.H. Kuiper, Manifolds which are like projective planes.